# Search input not showing exact match from csv when searched

Tags: php, csv

Following on from a previous question i have my form which is but at the moment whenever i have tried to enter a keyword the whole table is just displayed. Is there a way to get it showing only matches. For example if i searched Housing leeds. it would show the entire row in a table?

Housing Leeds,Yorkshire LL,3,2013,221,235

index.php

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="search.php" method="get">
        <label>
            Search
            <input type="text" name="search" autocomplete="off">
        </label>

            <input type="submit" name="Search">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

search.php

Help from another user:

search.php

```
 <?php

$search = isset($_GET['search']) ? (int) trim($_GET['search']) : null;
$search = isset($_GET['search']) ? trim($_GET['search']) : null;
$search = isset($_GET['search']) ? (int) trim($_GET['search']) : null;
$search = isset($_GET['search']) ? trim($_GET['search']) : null;
$search = isset($_GET['search']) ? trim($_GET['search']) : null;


define('CSV_INDEX_LANDLORD', 0);
define('CSV_INDEX_LANDLORD_GROUP', 1);
define('CSV_INDEX_QUARTER', 2);
define('CSV_INDEX_YEAR', 3);
define('CSV_INDEX_ESTIMATED_PROJECT_COST', 4);
define('CSV_INDEX_ACTUAL_PROJECT_COST', 5);



$row = 1;
$output = [];

if (($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        $row++;

        // if the user tried to search on year and it doesn't match, continue skips to the next row
        // casting ensures we compare integers with integers
        if (!empty($search) && stripos($data[CSV_INDEX_LANDLORD], $search) !== false) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!empty($search) && stripos($data[CSV_INDEX_LANDLORD_GROUP], $search) !== false) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!empty($search) && stripos($data[CSV_INDEX_QUARTER], $search) !== false) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!empty($search) && stripos($data[CSV_INDEX_ESTIMATED_PROJECT_COST], $search) !== false) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!empty($search) && stripos($data[CSV_INDEX_ACTUAL_PROJECT_COST], $search) !== false) {
            continue;
        }

        $output[] = $data;
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
?>

<?php if (!empty($output)): ?>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th><strong>Landlord</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Landlord Group</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Quarter</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Year</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Estimated Project Costs</strong></th>
            <th><strong>Actual Project Cost</strong>
        <tr>
        <?php foreach ($output as $row): ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?=$row[0]?></td>
            <td><?=$row[1]?></td>
            <td><?=$row[2]?></td>
            <td><?=$row[3]?></td>
            <td><?=$row[4]?></td>
            <td><?=$row[5]?></td>
        </tr>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </table>
<?php endif; ?>
```

I am struggling to get it to work so that if I enter either a Landlord or Landlord group data relating to it is shown in the table. Below is a line of CSV data. The bold are the headings.

```
 **Landlord,Landlord group,Quarter,Year,Estimated project costs (000s),Actual project cost (000s)**
Housing Leeds,Yorkshire LL,3,2013,221,235
```

Comment: the `<input>` in your form doesn't have a name. It has to have one to be referred to in `$_GET['inputname']`.

Comment: where should `$_GET['Landlord']` and all the others come from?

Comment: The bold in the question is the headers in the csv so I have assumed that this would work if I add in a name to the search. How would I get round it because I have many heading.

Answer (score 0):

You have several options here.

Make an input for every search-item you wanna use:

```
<input name="Landlord">
<input name="LandlordGroup">
<input name="Quarter">
...
```

then you can keep the php as is.
This of course is not very neat for the user.

Another option is to add a `select` item, which lets the user selct what to search for:

```
<input name="search">
<select name="searchItem">
    <option value="LANDLORD">Landlord
    <option value="LANDLORD_GROUP">Landlord Group
    <option value="QUARTER">Quarter
    //.. more items here to add
</select>
```

then you would do something like that in your php script:

```
<?php
$search = $_GET['search'];
$searchItem = $_GET['searchItem'];

// another way here to define the insexes as ass.Array, makes it easier later on.
// NOTE that the keys have to match the values of the select-options
$csvIndexes = array("LANDLORD"=>0,
                    "LANDLORD_GROUP"=>1,
                     "QUARTER"=>2,
                     //...
                   );
// $row = 1; // not needed here
$output = [];

if ($handle = fopen("data.csv", "r")) {
    while ($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) {
        // $num = count($data);
        // $row++;
        if (!empty($search) && stripos($csvIndexes[$searchItem], $search)) {
            $output[] = $data;
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
// leave the rest as is.
?>
```

I haven't tested this, since I don't have your csv, but I hope you get the idea!

A third option would be to search in every item per default.

Comment: Thanks very much I will give this a go. And see how I get on.

Comment: Just noticed that the data in the file is not comma separated, I will add in the commas in sublime. If I where to have just the search input would I just need to change the GEar super global to match the name in the input?

Comment: Sorry that should say _GET

Comment: Yes. `$_GET['nameoftheinput']` (case sensitive)

Comment: Okay so I have made some changes in my code above and its bringing back everything except those results

Comment: Yeah, because you didn't follow my suggestion. Tip: If you wanna go with the third option of my answer, then there's no need for 8 different `if strpos`. Just do one without the constants.

Comment: Sorry about that could you do me an example please? Just do I can see what you mean in code. Thanks

Comment: I have only one if statement now and removed the constants and replaced with '$search' but its still not working right. I just cant see why.

Comment: Tried a number of options but its still not working correctly, been trying for a few hours to debug it